# Multiple child components call action from 1 to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new with React.

I have component(JSX) having 3 child component A, B and C.

A Component : Have list of users

What i want, when i click on any user, component B and C should update with related information of clicked user and the user id should update in URL as well. And when i refresh the page it should load data.

Currently i am rendering B and C component using ReactDOM.render(), That is not good way to do so.

Thanks !

Comment: can you share your code what you did so far

Comment: You can download from here : http://navikumt.com/conversation.zip

Comment: Please do not share zip files for your code. Either put your code here directly or share it somewhere like codesandbox.org. You need to look React documentations, especially state and how to share it with other components. Also, with SPA you don't need to refresh page.

Comment: the zip file contain only 4 files, main layout and 3 child

Comment: @TonyStark please share your code here, not through zip files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this, where you share state between child components.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const A = ({ users, selectUser }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>I am A.</h1>
      {users.map((u, i) => {
        return <button onClick={() => selectUser(i)}>{u}</button>;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const B = ({ user }) => {
  return <h1>I am B. Current user: {user}</h1>;
};

const C = ({ user }) => {
  return <h1>I am C. Current user: {user}</h1>;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: ["bob", "anne", "mary"],
    currentUserIndex: 0
  };

  selectUser = n => {
    this.setState({
      currentUserIndex: n
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { users, currentUserIndex } = this.state;
    const currentUser = users[currentUserIndex];

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <A selectUser={this.selectUser} users={users} />
        <B user={currentUser} />
        <C user={currentUser} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l4xw1yrlql).

Comment: Hi Colin

This is working example but how can i will manage the userID in url to keep on refresh.

Comment: You should check out React Router if you want to put it in the URL, but if you just want to persist on refresh, then use local storage.

Comment: Hi Colin

Your answer helped me, Thanks for it.

Where i stuck is: I have 2 HTML tags to show alternate on mouse hover on element:

Example:

I have 2 elements A and B

By default i shown A and When user hover the mouse i Have to show B and when mouse out, Show A again.

I a list of user and each user have separate A and B.

If i manage it by STATE, it will update for all users at same.